# webapp-tracking tool to analyse user behaviour

Tags: javascript, tracking

I am looking for a library which will support me to track user behaviour on my webapp.

It is an intranet-app so I cannot use a tool like Google-Analytics. Moreover users access the app via IPads and desktop-browsers, so Flash-Counters are no option as well.

Currently I think I have to look for an JavaScript/JQuery-solution. Thanks in advance for some hints.

On serverside, I am using tomcat, java, java-server-faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend yo to use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). You can install it on your local network with minimun software/hardware requirements, It has a lot of features, not as much as Google Analitycs, but it's open source, and you can install on local environments like intranets.

I'm using [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) for couple of years, and for me, it worked great!